# Issue with jmx generated by Blazemeter Mobile Recorder

Tags: mobile, jmeter, recorder, blazemeter

So I am trying to record a Mobile Native App with Blazemeter Mobile Recorder.
After recording I have generated the .jmx file.
But the issue is this jmx file is not getting opened up with JMeter.
Getting the below error message.
 org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.httpsamplerproxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.hashtree

Request you to please help me with this.

Comment: Kindly provide the full **jmeter.log** file

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Please share your email ID, will mail the log file to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Dmitri,

PFB contents from log file.
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_IN 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\user.properties 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\system.properties 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2016 The Apache Software Foundation 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 3.0 r1743807 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_92 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 10 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=10.0 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Max memory     =523763712 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Available Processors =4 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (India) 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (India) 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 10.220.137.178 Name: IGTSGGN1IT2062 FullName: IGTSGGN1IT2062.interglobetechnologies.com 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform] 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2016/08/02 13:59:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2016/08/02 14:00:00 WARN  - org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem: Failed to load plugin updates info java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.getJSON(PluginManager.java:149)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:78)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem.<init>(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:22)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuCreator.getMenuItemsAtLocation(PluginManagerMenuCreator.java:22)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.addPluginsMenuItems(JMeterMenuBar.java:572)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.makeOptionsMenu(JMeterMenuBar.java:349)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.createMenuBar(JMeterMenuBar.java:268)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.<init>(JMeterMenuBar.java:161)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame.init(MainFrame.java:493)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:241)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:327)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)

2016/08/02 14:00:00 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils: JMeter-Plugins.org v.1.4.0 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\keytool' 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.DistributionGraphVisualizer 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2016/08/02 14:00:01 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SplineVisualizer 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Desktop\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin' 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Downloads\Recording_08_1,_2016,_6-32_am.jmx 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Downloads' 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.9 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Downloads\Recording_08_1,_2016,_6-32_am.jmx 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: Will only cache the following methods: [GET] 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2016/08/02 14:00:09 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\chetali.saxena\Downloads\Recording_08_1,_2016,_6-32_am.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
------------------------------- : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
-------------------------------
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
version             : 3.0 r1743807
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:539)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:503)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
------------------------------- : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
-------------------------------
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
version             : 3.0 r1743807
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.createConversionException(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:103)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:97)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1206)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1190)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1061)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:524)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/HTTPSamplerProxy[5]
line number         : 462
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:73)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 47 more

enter code here

Thanks,
Chetali
```